IF ELSE not running inside AWS EC2 user data
I am trying to run the following code inside EC2 user data but there no changes happening to the server
#!/bin/bash


echo 'export ENV_VAR=true' >> /etc/profile
          
if [[ "$ENV_VAR" == "true" ]]; then
  sudo yum -y install <pkg>
  sudo /url/local/bin --update-kernel=ALL --args=""
fi

but when running these commands independently on the server it is working.
I have tried to set the path to HOME=/home/ec2-user but didnt worked.
Is there a way possible to execute this block inside the user data??

Add after the echo command to "load" the variable:
. /etc/environment

This (with . ) will execute the command in the current shell and actually set the variable

thanks it worked :)

If you are happy with my answer you can consider to accept it (the ticke on the left, under the up/down votes)
